# How to create tooltip with one element in CSS

Tags: jquery, css, tooltip

I have a tooltip created with 3 elements and a wrapper

html:

```
<div class="tooltip-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/jcubic" title="" rel="Twitter">
        <img src="http://images.jcubic.pl/jcubic/profile-twitter.png">
    </a>
    <div class="tooltip" style="top: -34px; left: -18px; display: block; opacity: 0.9648882429441257;">
        <div class="box">Twitter</div>
        <div class="arrow" style="border-left-width: 5px; border-right-width: 5px; border-top-width: 5px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The inline styles are created by javascript (jQuery plugin).

and css:

```
.tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
}
.tooltip-wrapper .box {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #b72100;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.tooltip-wrapper .arrow {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;    
    border-top: 5px solid #b72100;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**is it posibble to create tooltip using only one element and css pseudo elements :after for arrow?**

```
<div class="tooltip">Twitter</div>
```

You can see demo [on my website](http://jcubic.pl/me) (the profiles icons).

I try to just merge `.tooltip` with `.box` the styles and create `tooltip:after { content: ''; }` from `.arrow` but the style don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Position `.box` relative and the `:after` absolute.

HTML:

```
<div class="tooltip-wrapper" style="position: relative;">
    <a href="https://twitter.com/jcubic" title="" rel="Twitter">
        <img src="http://images.jcubic.pl/jcubic/profile-twitter.png" />
    </a>
    <div class="tooltip" style="top: -34px; left: -18px; display: block; opacity: 0.9648882429441257;">
        <div class="box">Twitter</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip-wrapper .box {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #b72100;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; /* added this line */
}
.tooltip-wrapper .box:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;    
    border-top: 5px solid #b72100;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -3px;    
}
```

Also check this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/GUtn4/).

Comment: What about the box is it needed? Can it be just `<div class="tooltip">Twitter</div>`?

Comment: You can lose it, but then `.tooltip` needs to have a fixed width! Check http://jsfiddle.net/LinkinTED/GUtn4/2/